# Guard Page Exception - how to raise

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, exception

A customer that uses our API gets a guard page exception.
He uses VirtualAlloc and VirtualProtect.

When I run his example everything works fine.

I tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366549%28VS.85%29.aspx) example from Microsoft but VisualStudio does not throw an 0x80000001 exception even if I already turned it on in the exception menu under 'Debug'.
But the example clearly states that:

> The first attempt to lock the memory block fails, raising a STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION exception.

What do I need to do to get that exception?

Edit:

The customer does something like this:

```
SYSTEM_INFO systemInfo;
GetSystemInfo(&systemInfo);
DWORD dwPageSize = systemInfo.dwPageSize;
size_t size = width * height * sizeof(MyStruct); 
while(size % dwPageSize) 
{
    height--;
    size = width * height * sizeof(MyStruct); 
}

size_t dataSize = size + dwPageSize;

MyStruct * my_struct = (MyStruct*)VirtualAlloc(NULL, dataSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE , PAGE_READWRITE);
if (!my_struct) return;

LPVOID beginGuard = (char*)my_struct + size;
DWORD oldProtection;
BOOL b = VirtualProtect(beginGuard, dwPageSize, PAGE_READWRITE | PAGE_GUARD, &oldProtection);
if(!b) MessageBox(NULL, "Can't set guard page", "", 0);

doSomething(); // some API function
```

Somewhere in 'doSomething()' the mentioned exception gets thrown. But I can't help that customer because I don't get that exception.

Comment: Can you give us more details how the customer got guard page exception. Show us his example. As far as the sample from MSDN goes, you can see in the comments that its explanation is incorrect because `VirtualLock` does not raise an exception. It is quite obvious actually. I mean, there is no code that handles the exception in the whole snippet.

Comment: I edited my post for clarification.

Comment: So what are you saying, that `doSomething` represents some actions that the customer does to raise this exception and you do not know what they are? Have you tried accessing `my_struct`? Replace `doSomething` with `MyStruct foo = my_struct[0];`, and you should get 0x80000001 exception.

Comment: When he uses PAGE_GUARD then getting STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION should never be a surprise.  That's entirely the intention.  The hanky-panky with the `height` variable is very unlikely to be correct, it is pretty much doomed to become 0.  In which case any access to my_struct is going to trigger the exception.  Whatever it is meant to do (either dynamically extending the allocation or generating a buffer overflow diagnostic) is unlikely to pan out.  sizeof(my_struct) would have to be a multiple of 4096.

Comment: @HansPassant my problem here is, that I don't get any exception running this code. I really don't understand why not.

Answer (score 0):

To raise an exception with code 0x80000001, you need to try to access memory that is allocated and protected using `PAGE_GUARD` flag. Write something like

```
MyStruct foo = my_struct[0];
```

and the exception will be raised.

As far as the sample from MSDN goes, you can see in the comments of that post that its explanation is incorrect because `VirtualLock` does not raise an exception.

Comment: When I do as you said, no exception gets raised, still.

Comment: @thats_me What Windows version are you testing this on? I use Windows 7 x64. This code throws that exception when I run it. I am using VS2015, but still ... What happens when you build that sample and execute it from command prompt?

Comment: I'm also using Windows 7 x64 with VS 2010. Do you by any chance use Sophos AntiVirus? My current guess is, that some AntiVirus program is responsible for throwing that exception. (Just guessing in the blue.) Running the program from cmd does not do any difference.

Comment: @thats_me I do not use Sophos, nor does this have anything to do with AV. Throwing that exception is the expected behavior, as documented in description of `PAGE_GUARD` flag: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786(v=vs.85).aspx Did you try creating a sample app using just this code, or are you calling this inside your project? Maybe you have a try-catch block somewhere up in the function call hierarchy that handles this exception?

Comment: I did create a sample program and there is still no exception.

Comment: @thats_me I am running out of ideas ... Did you try to run this sample app on another machine?